# Minimize differences between dataframes/arrays with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, minimize, minimization

I have a dataframe containing the quarterly data, that looks like this:

| Country | Q1 | Q2 | Q1_ratio | Q2_ratio | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 70 | 30 | 0.7 | 0.3 | 100 |
| Canada | 60 | 40 | 0.6 | 0.4 | 100 |
| Japan | 40 | 60 | 0.4 | 0.6 | 100 |
| TOTAL | 170 | 130 |  |  |  |

My issue is this: **When I change the value in Total column, I need to recalculate the values for Q1 and Q2**, so that that the **sum of Q1 and Q2 equals the row total** and also the **column total of Q1 and Q2 can't change**. Also, the **Q1 and Q2 ratios should stay as close to the original values as possible** to keep the seasonality.

So, in other words, I need to minimize the difference between quarterly ratios before and after the total value update.

Example:
Let's say I change the total value for USA to 80, Canada to 90 and Japan to 130. If I keep the quarterly ratios exactly as they were before, I get this:

| Country | Q1 | Q2 | Q1_ratio | Q2_ratio | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 56 | 24 | 0.7 | 0.3 | 80 |
| Canada | 54 | 36 | 0.6 | 0.4 | 90 |
| Japan | 52 | 78 | 0.4 | 0.6 | 130 |
| TOTAL | 162 | 138 |  |  |  |

But this result doesn't comply with the second constraint (the quarterly column totals can't change).

If I keep the original column totals and do some trial and error to minimize the quarterly ratio differences, I get something like this:

| Country | Q1 | Q2 | Q1_ratio | Q2_ratio | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 58 | 22 | 0.725 | 0.275 | 80 |
| Canada | 56.5 | 33.5 | 0.628 | 0.372 | 90 |
| Japan | 55.5 | 74.5 | 0.427 | 0.573 | 130 |
| TOTAL | 170 | 130 |  |  |  |

I feel like this shouldn't be too hard to figure out but the solution eludes me. Any idea how to calculate this/ implement this in Python?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shared code, and I don't know exactly what your data looks like, so I'll answer accordingly in pseudocode. In fact this isn't really a Pandas question, besides for the simple extraction/replacement of data.

- The first step of the solution, which you show, is to calculate the difference in totals (`new Total - old Total`), and for each row, for each quarter, multiply the change by that quarter's ratio. This way your ratio is exactly preserved (the middle table in your example).
- Now for your second constraint, we calculate the difference between the new column totals and the old ones (ie `170 - 162` and `130 - 138`). We see that Q1 needs +8 and Q2 needs -8, so we will distribute this according to the following ratio
- Divide each ratio column by the sum of the column. So 0.7 = 0.41, 0.6 = 0.35, etc.
- Then for each country multiply the column diff (ie +8 and -8) by this ratio.

This yields:

```
    Country Q1      Q2   Q1_ratio Q2_ratio Total
0   USA     59.29   22.15   0.74    0.28    80
1   Canada  56.82   33.54   0.63    0.37    90
2   Japan   53.88   74.31   0.41    0.57    130
```

Which is about the same as you got by hand.

Note that this solution does not using analytical minimisation techniques, but just applies row and column ratios in order.